# NSString : leak when assigning value to a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, properties, nsstring

Assuming we don't use ARC.
Suppose we have a very simple class in which we declare 2 NSString properties, like this :

```
@interface Foo : UIView {}
-(id)initWithArguments:(NSString*)mess title:(NSString*)tit;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *message;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@end
```

and in implementation :

```
@implementation Foo
@synthesize message, title;

-(id)initWithArguments:(NSString*)mess title:(NSString*)tit{
if((self = [super init])){
message = mess; // (1)
self.title = tit; // (2)
(...)
}
return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
message = nil;
title = nil;
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Now if I call a method from another class, in which I create 2 NSString and an instance of Foo , like this :

```
-(void)someMethod{
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some text with %d things", 5];
NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"other text with %d things", 5];

Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithArguments:string1 title:string2];
}
```

The whole code works fine and doesn't crash, but, if I profile it with instruments,

- it doesn't cause a leak when calling (1)("message = mess;")
- it cause a leak when calling (2)("self.title = tit;")

It's very confusing, because stringWithFormat is an autoreleased object, isn't it ?
So, how an autoreleased object can cause a leak when assigning to a property ???

I read somewhere that it's almost always better to use the "self.text = value;" form instead of the "text = value;" form, because the second one may cause a leak.

Actually, in this code it's the contrary.

And... If I use a constant NSString like @"some text", instead of the values returned by [NSString stringWithFormat], there is no leak, of course.

Any idea ?

Comment: So why aren't you using `self.message = mess;`?

Comment: try to avoid to use the keyword `retain` in ARC, it is compiled as `strong` in that particular case, but it would be better if _you_ specify the properties' properties explicitly, like using the `strong` or `copy` in case of `NSString`. btw, who told you there is a leak here?

Comment: As I said in the beginning, I don't use ARC. And the leak appears when profiling the app with instruments.

Comment: didn't you forget to `release` your objects in `dealloc` method? And your `initWithArguments:title:` method implementation is wrong. Check how to write init methods

Comment: Yes you are init'ing and wrong and dont dealloc.  You really should use ARC, it just saves lots of hassle and there is no down side.

Comment: Shamsiddin, what is wrong in my init code ? For clarity purposes, I didn't wrote all the code present in the init method, for example the "if((self = [super init]))" and the "return self;" statements. I was thinking it was obvious, no ? And of course, the dealloc method still contains "[message release];" and "[title release];".

Comment: I edited the code and added a few pieces of code which I had previously ommited.

Comment: To release: `self.message = nil;` etc.  You must invoke the setter/getter!

Comment: Hello, trojanfoe, actually, my code contains in the dealloc : "message = nil;" and "title = nil;". I fixed this in my message. Do you mean I have to explicitly invoke the setter/getter with "self." in the dealloc ?

Comment: Yes.   And in `init` (as per my first comment).

Comment: Hello again, Trajanfoe. -You're perfectly right : I simply forgot the "self." in the two statements of the dealloc ! If I write "self.message = mess;" in init and "self.message = nil;" in the dealloc, it works and it doesn't leaks ! May I suggest you write a short answer ? (I you don't want, I will answer my question myself.)

Comment: @trojanfoe it isn't necessary to implement setter/getter methods.

Comment: @Shamsiddin I didn't say it was necessary to implement the setter/getter, but it is necessary to invoke them.

Comment: @Chrysotribax, now your `dealloc` method is wrong. With which instance variables connected your properties those should be `release`'ed in `dealloc` method. Dont' release directly your properties. or release your properties with `self.` prefix.

Comment: Thank you, shamsiddin : you're right. See trojanfoe answer. I fixed this in my code and now it works without leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to invoke the (compiler-generated) setter methods in a few cases:

```
self.message = mess;    // in init method

self.message = nil;     // in dealloc method
self.title = nil;       // ditto
```

It's crucial that you use the setter/getter methods in non-ARC code.

Comment: Many thanks trajanfoe : this is sometimes very confusing of how to use properties correctly in obj-C, even if you are coding since numerous years.